# Dojo Combobox not rending properly in XPages

Tags: dojo, xpages

My team is having a strange issue with the dojo combobox.  When we moved the code to the integration environment, the dojo combobox started to render improperly.  We verified that the code is the same.  Strangely other dojo comboboxes in the same application render normally.

The integration server is on a older version: 9.0.1 HF32  64 bit

The unit server where it works is at: 9.0.1 FP3 HF632

UNIT SERVER rendering on left, INTG Server rendering on right.

[image: UNIT Server]
  [image]

My question is has anybody seen this and do they know how to fix it?

Notes:

- this happens in IE and Chrome. It is coming wrong from the server.
- We are using CIAO to promote between environments (which I hate).
- Upgrading the server is not an option for me
- I can post code if requested, but I suspect that it isn't a code issue.

---

UPDATE:  For some reason the following two CSS files are not loaded on that particular page. **They are loaded on every other page in the application.** I can't find any property or setting that would effect this. The admin verified that these files are on the server and the dates are identical. These are system generated resources.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/oneuiv2.1/base/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/oneuiv2.1/defaultTheme/dojoTheme.css">
```

Does anyone know why these two stylesheets are not being loaded??

Comment: Not sure what's in HF32, but 9.0.1 FP3 has dojo 1.9.4. Originally 9.0.1 GA had dojo 1.8.3. Still, you'd expect the combobox to display normally regardless. Maybe confirm the dojo version on both servers and extlib versions too.

Comment: My guess is the browser has a problem to get style sheets/resources from integration server. Doublecheck network transfers in develop tab of the browser - you will probably find 401-404 errors there.

Comment: @Brian, the ext lib is the same for both servers. I don't really know what HF32 means either, the admin said it has no fix packs installed.

Comment: Both dojo versions are 1.9.7

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth, no 401-404 errors, but did see a different number of resources loaded.   domino-default.css was missing from the broken copy.    This must be system generated. Is this a clue Brian?

Comment: Steve, compare the domino/html directory in the Domino data directory on the two servers. I've seen a server where files were missing

Comment: Thanks @PerHenrikLausten. I will do that, but I have to get someone else to do it for me next Monday.

Comment: Does your broken XPage open with somewhat different URL pattern? Like old Domino links format, or with URL parameter or something? Your CSS is relative link, so it may be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I honestly don't remember what I did to fix this. It did get fixed and the project was deployed 2 years ago and was a success.

Comment: @SteveZavocki Please, close this question.

Comment: I just saw your comment Frantisek, I honestly don't remember what the resolution to this issue was. I am not sure how to "close this question" short of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some strange positioning issues depending on where Dojo comboboxes are relative to the browser screen, i.e. if there's not enough space left in the screen to position relative to the field they're bound to. That may have been in XPiNC and was in older versions. The thing to check is whether the rendering issue is related to where the field is relative to the page in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Paul, it doesn't appear to be related to where it is on the screen.  The rest of the page is the same on both servers.